# Пример использования HTTPListener.GetContextAsync()

Tags: c#, http, асинхронность

Никак не удается найти пример использования этого метода. Сколько я смог понять, он нужен для того чтобы ожидать соединения не порождая при этом дополнительных потоков. Его работа станет заметна, к примеру, в такой ситуации:
Обращаются к серверу несколько клиентов, и первый из них посылает большое количество данных, тогда, если не использовать этот метод, все остальные клиенты вынуждены будут ждать пока первый закончит передачу.
Пожалуйста, поправьте если я не прав.
И очень хотелось бы увидеть корректный пример использования метода т.к. остается не ясным даже как его запускать, ведь нельзя же его запускать в бесконечном цикле как обычный GetContext().

Comment: Есть много примеров "пример использования асинхронной процедуры". Все они похожи.

Comment: @nick_n_a у меня проблемы именно с этой, я вижу много примеров как работать с обычным HTTPListener.GetContext(), но ничего не могу найти про GetContextAsync().

Comment: @nick_n_a К примеру, GetContext часто вызывают в бесконечном цикле, а как быть с асинхронной его версией, мне непонятно.

Comment: Ещё раз вам пишу, читайте "асинхронный вызов", например https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2e08f6yc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @nick_n_a К сожалению, мне не очевидно как это соотноситься с моим вопросом, не могли бы вы переписать следующий код используя асинхронную версию метода: 
while (true)
{
    var context == listener.GetContext();
    Task.run(() => HandleContext(context));
   }

Comment: @КонстантинГалиахметов, я не знаю что такое конкретно GetContext, но предполагаю, что асинхронная версия Вашего кода будет такой:
while (true) { var context = await listener.GetContextAsync(); Task.run(() => HandleContext(context)); }

Comment: @Qutrix Насколько я могу судить, код переписанный таким образом, будет работать точно также. Так как цикл продолжит выполняться только после того как отработает GetContextAsync, а соответственно никакой асинхронности не прибавиться.

Comment: @КонстантинГалиахметов, прибавится. Разница в том, что в Вашем случае у Вас будет кол-во потоков равное количеству вызовов GetContext, но они будут ожидать, а в моем будет 0 ожидающих потоков, а для обработки (когда будет срабатывать GetContextAsync) будут браться потоки из пула. В общем - читайте конкретно про асинхронность тут по тэгу async\await